# WebRTC internet explorer support via JsSIP

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webrtc, sip, jssip

We are working on call to SIP via JsSIP library, with modern browsers like Chrome Firefox we don't have any poblems, but IE support is hell.
Does anyone has usecases with JsSIP in IE?

Answer (score 2):

SIP and WebRTC are two different technologies.

> but IE support is hell

[official IE support for WebRTC is non-existend.](http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc)

But if you're just interested in supporting the signalling layer of the application with JSsip which uses [WebSockets](http://jssip.net/documentation/0.6.x/overview/) you might be able to support Sip signalling as of [IE10](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets).

There are a [couple](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/) of [projects](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins) which implement the WebRTC API (`getUserMedia`, `peerConnection` etc) via Browser plugins. But last time I tried them (June 2014), they proved to be unreliable.